# Windows 8.1 pro activation cannot complete

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-activation

I built up a new custom PC and installed windows 8.1 pro from flash disk. Then I tried to activate by clicking "Buy product key" but it takes me to Microsoft website and says "Sorry, but you can’t activate this copy of Windows online. To activate, go to a store that sells Windows and buy a Windows Get Genuine kit."

I have 2 questions actually?

1. If I buy Windows 8.1 pro and use its serial key, would it work?
2. Why does it say "you can't activate **this** copy of Windows online" and suggests Windows Get Genuine kit? 
   Windows Get Genuine kit is almost double price.

I'm so confused, I'm going to purchase it but I don't wanna waste my money with the wrong product or version!

When I contact Microsoft, they no more sell windows 8.1 pro and the representative says that they can't say anything about the products bought from other than Microsoft! I'm stuck at this point.